# React-Flow: Can you pass props to a custom node in React-Flow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-flow

I am using React-Flow in order to visualise a tree hierarchy of components in React. And whenever you create a custom node in React-Flow, you use it in the tree like that:

```
  <ReactFlow
      onLoad={onLoadTree}
      elements={nodesAndEdges}
      nodeTypes={{ reactComponent: ComponentNode }}
```

Which makes it impossible to pass props. Let's say that I want to pass something, then I would be able to do that if the syntax was like `reactComponent: <ComponentNode myProps={myProps} />`. Has anyone worked with this technology before and knows if it's somehow possible to pass props to a custom node? :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass any data you want in the data property section when creating a new node :

```
const newNode = {
  ...nodeProps,
  data: {
    myCustomProps: "test",
  },
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do like this

```
const YourComponent = () => {
  const componentNode = { reactComponent: (props) => <ComponentNode myProp="myProps" {...props} />};

  return (
    <ReactFlow
      onLoad={onLoadTree}
      elements={nodesAndEdges}
      nodeTypes={componentNode}
    />
  );
};
```

Here through props you get the predefined props like data, id etc.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can pass props in `data` property of node.

Answer (score 1):

Hello from December 2022:

**withProps HOC:**

```
import { createElement } from 'react';

const withProps = (WrappedComponent, additionalProps = {}) => {
    return (props) => {
        return createElement(WrappedComponent, {
            ...props,
            ...additionalProps,
        });
    };
};

export default withProps;
```

**Component:**

```
const myNodeTypes= React.useMemo(
    () => ({
        myNode: withProps(myNode, { myProp }),
    }), [] 
);


<ReactFlow
    nodeTypes={myNodeTypes}
>
</ReactFlow>
```